# php Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['

Tags: php

When I run this script on my local server it works just fine.  However when I run it on a hostgator server I get this error:

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/user/public_html/parsing/parse.php on line 46
```

Line 46 is this:
$rows = [];

Any idea why this could be happening?
Thank you. 
By the way I have only copied up to line 46, there are a few more lines of code than shown here.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? [Short array syntax was added in PHP 5.4.0](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php).

Comment: Change `$rows = [];` to `$rows = array();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new array syntax `[]` is only available in versions 5.4 and greater.

If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.4 you have to use this syntax to create an empty array

```
$row = array();
```

Comment: Did you say 5.4? On cpanel it says this:
A newer version of phpMyAdmin is available and you should consider upgrading. The newest version is 4.2.7.1, released on 2014-08-17.

Comment: In the PHP manual is says [THIS](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) Check what version of PHP is running on your hostgator hosting package

Comment: You are right, this solved it.  What should I change this line of code to in order to prevent the error?  Thanks
$row_start = [$file_id, 0, 'NOW()'];

Comment: Try `$row_start = array($file_id, 0, 'NOW()');`

Comment: I would ask your host to upgrade the version of PHP they are using. The current STABLE version of PHP is now PHP5.5.16 and PHP5.6 will be out any day now.

Comment: Perfect.  Last question. How about this:
$fields[] = $item['Field']

Comment: That line should be OK

Comment: I have asked them and they refuse.  Hostgator is useless.

Comment: Now Im getting this error:
 Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/as1609/public_html/ParseBanksPhase1/parse.php on line 25
where line 25 is:
$file_info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

Comment: @ArjunSingh. PHP is a programming language. phpMyAdmin is a program written in that language. The version number of phpMyAdmin has no direct relationship with the version number of PHP.